# With Solace PubSub+ what does "MESSAGE_SPOOL_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE" mean?

Tags: python, solace

I am trying to programmatically create a queue on a Solace PubSub+ (`solace/solace-pubsub-standard`) container using python and swagger.

I've successfully managed to query the api to find existing message vpns and create new ones, so I'm reasonably certain that I have the basic python/swagger API working correctly.

However, whenever I try to query the api to find existing queues or create new queues, I receive some variation of:

```
E           semp_client.rest.ApiException: (400)
E           Reason: Bad Request
E           HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 09 Sep 2020 14:56:10 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'Solace_VMR/9.6.0.32', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store'})
E           HTTP response body: {
E               "meta":{
E                   "error":{
E                       "code":412,
E                       "description":"Problem with reading: message spool data not available",
E                       "status":"MESSAGE_SPOOL_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE"
E                   },
E                   "request":{
E                       "method":"GET",
E                       "uri":"http://localhost:32835/SEMP/v2/config/msgVpns/message_vpn_name/queues"
E                   },
E                   "responseCode":400
E               }
E           }

semp_client/semp_client/rest.py:228: ApiException
```

Does anyone know what `MESSAGE_SPOOL_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE` means?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error few days back. It essentially occurs when you're trying to perform an action on the spooled messages but the backend filesystem configured for backing up those spooled messages is not mounted. In that case you might have to query the right solace appliance which is active and has those spool mounts present.

Comment: is there any where which can instruct me to properly mount the spools?